# GroupString and IsGroupRender in displayform URL

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, url, display-form

We have migrated MOSS 2007 sites to SP 2010 using db attach detach. As part of that we have deployed the custom solutions wsp on the SP 2010 site. I tried to open the display form of a list, when the see the url its like this:

```
http://sitename/Lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?List={listid}&
ID=itemid&
Source=http://sitename/Lists/listname/customview.aspx?
GroupString=%253B%2523%253B2523&
IsGroupRender=TRUE&
ContentTypeId=0x01006E4E5A11F22E9943A062D982A1B39F0E0100FD2B8FEE87033E46A0AF022795CA7467&
IsDlg=1
```

Could someone help me in understanding `GroupString` and `IsGroupRender` parameters in the URL.